# scipy sparse A[:,0] = ndarray ValueError

Tags: indexing, scipy, sparse-matrix, valueerror

Setting the first row of a scipy sparse array `A[0,:] = np.ones()` works fine, 
but trying to set the first column with `A[:,0] = np.ones()` raises a ValueError. 
Is this a bug in scipy 1.5.2, or have I not found doc which describes this ?

Answer 13 sep: this is a known bug area, see [issues/10695](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10695)
and the newest [scipy/sparse/_index.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/_index.py).
However I have not tested `A[:,0]` with this.

```
""" scipy sparse A[:,0] = ndarray ValueError """
# sparse A[0,:] = ndarray works, sparse A[:,0] = ndarray raises ValueError
# https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[scipy] [sparse-matrix] ValueError  > 100

import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
# import warnings
# warnings.simplefilter( "ignore", sparse.SparseEfficiencyWarning )

def versionstr():
    import numpy, scipy, sys
    return "versions: numpy %s  scipy %s  python %s " % (
        numpy.__version__, scipy.__version__ , sys.version.split()[0] )

print( versionstr() )  # 11 Sep 2020: numpy 1.19.2  scipy 1.5.2  python 3.7.6

#...........................................................................
n = 3
ones = np.ones( n )

for A in [
        np.eye(n),
        sparse.eye( n ).tolil(),
        sparse.eye( n ).tocsr(),
        sparse.eye( n ).tocsr(),
        ]:
    print( "\n-- A:", type(A).__name__, A.shape )
    print( "A[0,:] = ones" )
    A[0,:] = ones
    print( "A: \n", getattr( A, "A", A ))  # dense

        # first column = ones --
    if sparse.issparse( A ):
        A[:,0] = ones.reshape( n, 1 )   # ok
        A[:,0] = np.matrix( ones ).T    # ok
        A[range(n),0] = ones            # ok
    try:
        print( "A[:,0] = ones" )
        A[:,0] = ones                   # A dense ok, A sparse ValueError
    except ValueError as msg:
        print( "ValueError:", msg )
        # ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9 into shape (3,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably call this a bug, yes - that's not the behavior I would have expected. Under the hood, it looks like this is driven by `np.broadcast_arrays()`, which is called when the fill array is dense. This function treats 1d arrays as if they're 2d (1, N) arrays. I would have expected based on the behavior of numpy slicing that a 1d array would be used without broadcasting if the size is correct.

Column slices:

```
>>> np.broadcast_arrays(np.ones((3,1)), A[:,0].A)
[array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]]), array([[1.],
       [0.],
       [0.]])]
>>> np.broadcast_arrays(np.ones((3,)), A[:,0].A)
[array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]]), array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])]
>>> np.broadcast_arrays(np.ones((1, 3)), A[:,0].A)
[array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]]), array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])]
```

Row slices:

```
>>> np.broadcast_arrays(np.ones((3, )), A[0, :].A)
[array([[1., 1., 1.]]), array([[1., 0., 0.]])]
>>> np.broadcast_arrays(np.ones((3, 1)), A[0, :].A)
[array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]]), array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])]
>>> np.broadcast_arrays(np.ones((1, 3)), A[0, :].A)
[array([[1., 1., 1.]]), array([[1., 0., 0.]])]
```